# How to add CSS to a after pseudo element with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a icon minus with a after element to make it look like a plus,and the idea was that the after element would rotate to lay on top of the minus whenever it was clicked.

```js
$(".bonuses .wrapper .header ::after").css('transform', 'translateY(-50%) rotate(88deg)');
```

```html
  <div class="bonuses">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
            <h2>What's included?</h2>
        </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)